# Loading more items on button click and using the same foreach again, the same way Laravel Pagination shows the next page. Using Laravel/JS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, infinite-scroll

On my site I have a news page showing (for testing purposes) the 5 most recent items. If there are more items in the database than these 5 which are currently shown, there will be a "load more items" button. When this button is clicked I would like to load 5 more items from the database.

Now getting these items is not the problem. The problem is I would like to add these items at the bottom of the page using the same foreach the previous items have used. I was wondering if there is a way to do this in Laravel?

For example:
On the first load of the page the first 5 items are shown with the following foreach and If/else.

```
    //not the exact code, but you get the idea
    @foreach($items as $item)
      @if($count < $limit && !item->hidden)
        @if(day = today)
          //do something
        @endif
        @if(day = yesterday)
          //do something
        @endif
      @endif
    @endforeach

    @if($count == $items && $moreItemsAvailable)
       <button> Load more news </button>
    @endif
```

So now if the "load more news"-button is clicked I would like to get more news from the database (not a problem) and add it at the bottom of the page by using that same foreach again (the actual problem).
I have seen that the standard Pagination by Laravel does this when switching page.

I know I could get the data and put all the if's and elses in Javascript again, but that is not very neat and adds a lot of code to the page. If I could re-use the code that would be perfect.

How can I do this for my situation, so with a button instead of tabs and adding it to the bottom of it?

Comment: PHP code only runs when the page loads, so you will have to either reload the page, or do this with javascript/ajax

Comment: Is there a way to make some sort of template which gets called for loading the items, so I do not have to write that code twice on a page?

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up a route which takes the page number (and any additional parameters you may need). That route controller renders a simple blade template which contains just your `@foreach`.
Then in your listing page just fetch the html for page=1 after loading.
(Or I guess you can `@include` the template which renders the first records.)